# Retrieve client computer username using nodejs

Tags: node.js, server, client-server

Can anyone tell me how to retrieve client computer username through nodejs.
i have wrote a nodejs program...

```
//logging the socket address
function start(httpserver) {

var sockets = {};

var io = socketio(httpserver);



io.on('connection', function (socket) {


        });

//receiving message
socket.on('user message', function (msg) {
    console.log('message: ' + msg);


});

//disconnection
socket.on('disconnect', function (msg) {

});

socket.on('foo', function (msg) {
    console.log('received foo:'+msg);
});



});


}
```

when i start the nodejs server it picks up index.html and connects to port 8888. Similarly, I am able to connect from client computer.. Eg:HOSTNAME:8888

But how do i retrieve client computer username

Answer (score 0):

Rverse DNS resolution (rDNS) will do the trick.

It is the querying of the Domain Name System (DNS) to determine the domain name associated with an IP address – the reverse of the usual "forward" DNS lookup of an IP address from a domain name.

```
const clientIp = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';

require('dns').reverse(clientIp, function(err, domains) {

    console.log(domains);
});
```

Reference:

- https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_reverse_ip_callback

To get the client ip using socketio, you could consult the following stub:

```
socketio.on("connection", function (socket) {
   const clientIp = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;
   // Do the reverse DNS lookup
});
```